# Zendesk API using R

Tags: r, zendesk

I'm trying to integrate the zendesk API using R. Following is the code

```
library(zendeskR)
library(rjson)
zendesk("username", "password", "URL")
a <- getTicket("69254")
```

Result is

> Error in fromJSON(result[[i]]) : no data to parse

Comment: Welome to SO. This is a very broad question with little to help guide anyone to help you. You should first read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE). Then you should rephrase your question appropriately before it get's little positive attention from the SO community.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I have rephrased my question. Hope it is better now.

Comment: Better. What have you done to confirm that there is a JSON endpoint serving data from your zendesk? In other words, how do you know that R is wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going wrong here R or json. Prior to asking on SO, I googled and was following this link : https://github.com/tcash21/zendeskR

Comment: OK, so you now need to eliminate something bad on the zendesk end. [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction) are some docs showing how to query the zendesk API from the command line using `curl`. Things like `curl -u jdoe@example.com:hdtR9Ve6 https://obscura.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json` depending on how you have set up the AUTH on zendesk. Once you get good output from `curl` you can be pretty certain that the problem is on the R side. There are other ways to get json from R directly, after you verify it outside of R using the `curl` or similar transparent method.

Comment: You should check out ngDesk instead as its totally free and has awesome features. You can check it out here https://www.ngdesk.com